# AngularFire : Firebase App not initialized when accessed from App Component

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Been working with Angular and Firebase ok using AngularFire, that is, I've been accessing all angular auth from components other than the `app.component.ts`.

`Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)." name:"[DEFAULT]`

I can only assume Firebase is being init later than the app component? Is there a way around this? Following are the concerned parts.

**App Component :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  router;
  constructor(router: Router) {
    this.router = router;

    //Fails here.
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Works in a normal component.

```
...
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: '....component',
  templateUrl: './....component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./....component.scss']
})
export class CustomComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.user = {};
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (!user) {
        router.navigate(['../login']);
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**App Module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverside' }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

D you try to put the AngularFireModule import before the RouterModule import?

*Recommendation: Use a Guard in the routes for the redirect to login component*